# Configuring Xdebug with Intellij not working

Tags: intellij-idea, xdebug

I have spent hours getting XDebug to work with Intellij, but with no luck unfortunately.

My setup is as follows. I am on a Windows 7 machine, I have Intellij 12 installed. My PHP site runs on a Vmware virtual Linux (debian) box.

I have configured the following Xdebug settings in php.ini.

```
; xdebug settings
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/usr/lib/php5/xdebug-output"
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.71
xdebug.show_exception_trace=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

- 192.168.1.71 is the IP of my virtual server, but I also tried www.local-example.com.
- The site runs ok (I mapped the IP to www.local-example.com)
- phpinfo() tells me PHP is configured with xdebug: (Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies **with Xdebug** v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethan
- When I var_dump something it is formatted nicely by xdebug, so this part works.
- I ran my phpinfo() output through the wizard at http://xdebug.org/wizard.php and followed the steps that were suggested to me successfully.
- I had a nice long look at the flowchart here: https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/www/php/debug-setup-flowchart.pdf
- I copied the script at the following url and ran it from the command line: https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/howto_check_xdebug_installation. When I start the script nothing really happens, so I suppose its listening for connections (I'm not too Linux-savvy :). When I subsequently request one of my site's pages with the XDEBUG_SESSION_START=mysession parameter, the page loads, but very slowly.

All that really happens when I enable the xdebug settings in PHP.ini is that my site becomes slow.

You might wonder why I put Intellij in the title. I was trying to connect to xdebug from Intellij. but I have left intellij, because I think something is wrong with my basic xdebug setup.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP that you use, should be the IP of the machine running the IDE - **not** the one with PHP/Xdebug on it. Xdebug acts as the client, and the IDE as the server, and in order for Xdebug to connect to the IDE/server, it needs to know the IP address of that.

Alternatively, you can set xdebug.remote_conneck_back=1 to let Xdebug use the IP of the machine that makes the browser request (often the same as the machine/IP with the IDE on it).

Comment: Ah, that clears it up. I changed the IP in php.ini to the IP of my development machine and that didn't work at first. I was using NAT on my VMWare image, which puts the VMWare image in a different network (192.168.1.xx instead of 192.168.0.xx of my dev machine). When I switched to "bridged" networking mode on VMWare XDebug started to work. I then had to do some fiddling in the Intellij debug configuration, because of an Intellij "Can't find a local copy of the file on server..." message (http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/292918) and now it works! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> correct settings for xdebug on intelliJ IDEA on windows wamp is  look
>   for php.ini file find xdebug at bottom,

```html
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
```